# Noindex, nofollow - is placing them in HTTP response enough?

Tags: http, httprequest, search-engine, robots.txt

I think that question's title says it all - while developing and deploying betas, should I put

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
```

in HTTP response, or

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

in `<head></head>` section of every page?

Comment: Sepends on what you want to achieve by that. If the goal is to prevent web robots to index the pages, then it is better to use a ´robots.txt´ file and simply prevent indexing of that pages in general. This works reliable, all well-behaving robots obey those files. There is no such protection against bad robots - if you publish pages without restriction then not using them is a voluntary act by bots, they can be programmed to not obey.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde both yes and no. I'm programmer, someone else in our company is SEO specialist and he asked me to add `noindex, nofollow` to our beta site. I thought that adding this to `HTTP header` will be enough, but he told me it's not. That's why I asked my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X-Robots-Tag header and the robots meta tag have exactly the same meaning to any robot that supports them both. The robots meta tag is a much older standard. The X-Robots-Tag header was later introduced as an alternative to robots meta, for webmasters who had control over server config but not over the site code.

The one difference is that the X-Robots-Tag header is not quite as widely supported as the robots meta tag. If you only care about major search engines, either one is fine, but if you need it to work on older web robots, the meta tag is the better bet.

Note that neither of these prevent the robot from reading pages from your site, they just tell the robot not to index anything or follow any links. If you want to stop web robots from requesting any pages at all, you might consider using robots.txt instead.

Answer (score 0):

The META Tag should do it pretty well for you. All the big search engines read the meta tag that has the robots name and NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW content.

Comment: I get it, but what about header data? Robots ignore it?